# Cannot browse dimension hierarchy in cube browser

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas, olap

I have designed dimensions and a cube in SSAS. I cannot see my dimension hierarchy in cube browser UI. All data are shown as tabular format.

[Customer Dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faDvx.png)

But when I try to browse the cube I get the followin result:
[sales cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWMqz.png)

Please Help

Comment: It looks to me like you've opened up your customer dimension and the first thing you are seeing is your country level of the customers hierarchy.  So far it seems correct to me.  Click on the [+] notes to drill down farther.

Comment: I can see drilldown (+) when I browse the dimension structure. But I cannot see it when I browse the cube's itself.

Comment: It's right there on your screenshot... you are looking at it.  Remove Customer Key from the grid and without its uniqueness you'll see the rows collapse to the city grain, and Sales Amount will convert to the sum appropriate at that level.  (make sure u are using the columns from the hierarchy tho, and not the similarly named fields that are just dimension attributes).

Comment: I have removed the CustomerKey.And still browse cube data as tabular format.

Comment: SSMS (since 2012 I think) only supports tabular formatting of data. Older versions of SSMS (2008) supported hierarchical views.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. So, I cannot make drilldown operations on my cube data,right?

Comment: I found some similar answers at the following link:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1230d44f-68c9-4caa-985b-ccdb817daf75/how-to-enable-drill-down-option-in-ssas-2012?forum=sqlanalysisservices

Answer (score 0):

The drill-down feature in cube browser has been depreciated therefore you have to use other cube browsers like MS Excel